# Java Hibernate Many-To-Many HQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, join, many-to-many, hql

I have tables with Many-To-Many relation as the following:

```
Clubmember (member_id   int(11) not null auto_increment,
member_name varchar(50), address varchar(100))

Film(film_id    int(11) Not null auto_increment
title varchar(50), release_date varchar(10))

Rent(member_id  int(11) Not null,
film_id int(11) Not null
primary key(filmId, member_id),
foreign key(member_id) references(clubMember.memberId),
foreign key(film_id) references(film.filmId)
)
```

and use Many-to-Many annotation to model the classes as the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ClubMember")

public class ClubMember {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="member_id")
    private int memberId;

    @Column (name="member_name")
    private String name;

    @Column (name="address")
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="renter")
    private Set<Film> rentedFilm=new HashSet<Film>();
    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Film")
public class Film {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="film_id")
    private int filmId;
    @Column (name="title")
    private String filmTitle;
    @Column (name="release_date")
    private String releaseDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="RENT",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="film_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="member_id")})
    private Set<ClubMember> renter=new HashSet<ClubMember>();

}
```

And I am trying to retrieve all film that is rented by a particular clubmember.
With Sql I would write something like:

```
select Clubmember.member_id,  Clubmember.member_name, Film.title from ClubMember,Rent,Film 
Where Clubmember.member_id = Rent.member_id and Film.film_id=Rent.film_id;
```

I tried to use HQL, but i found some trouble:

I have tried something like this

```
 "Select F.filmId, F.filmTitle, M.name From Film F join F.renter M where F.filmId = :fId and M.memberId=:mId "
```

and supply the argument for `fId` and `mId` from two queries of

`Select memberId from ClubMember` and `Select filmId from Film`

But the result is the HQL query is malformed with exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 116 [Select F.filmId, F.filmTitle, M.name   From com.mycontact.manytomany.Film F join F.renter M where F.filmId = :fId0_, :fId1_, :fId2_ and M.memberId=:mId0_, :mId1_ ]
```

In fact I am quite not clear how to query this kind of request with HQL. Can anybody please give some hint.

Versions of jars for hibernate:
hibernate-annotations : 3.3.0.GA
hibernate-commons-annotations: 3.0.0.GA
hibernate-c3p0: 3.6.3.Final

Creating the query :

```
    List listFilmId=session.createQuery("Select F.filmId from Film F").list();
    List listMemberId=session.createQuery("Select M.memberId from ClubMember M").list();


    Query diffQuery=session.createQuery("Select F.filmId, F.filmTitle, M.name  "
            + " From Film F join F.renter M where F.filmId = :fId and M.memberId=:mId ");


    diffQuery.setParameterList("fId", listFilmId);
    diffQuery.setParameterList("mId", listMemberId);
```

Comment: How do you create the query? And what are the versions of Hibernate and related jars?

Comment: Versions of jars for hibernate: hibernate-annotations : 3.3.0.GA hibernate-commons-annotations: 3.0.0.GA hibernate-c3p0: 3.6.3.Final